# How do you run two different web servers (i.e. processes) on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

I want to run both my Rails api server and NodeJS frontend server(Express server that serves a React app) on one Heroku app.

I use multiple-buildpacks to build both Rails and Node successfully. However, I am not sure how to run both Puma (Rails) and Express (Nodejs) at the same time. Express will serve all requests to `/` and Puma will serve all requests to `/api/*`.

*A possible solution is using [runit](https://github.com/dpiddy/heroku-buildpack-runit)* but I am shy to use it because it's not an official buildpack by Heroku.

Comment: I dont think heroku support that. cant you create 2 different apps and they can talk to each other?